# Woocommerce: Can't put items in cart in iframe and on iphone

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, iframe, google-chrome, iphone

I have the following problem:
I have a Wordpress page that contains a Woocommerce store. This page is embedded in an iframe on a typo3 page.
If I visit the typo3 page with Google Chrome it is not possible to add products to the shopping cart. There is no error message, but the cart remains empty. The same problem occurs when I open the page on my iphone.

When I open the page in Firefox, Internet Explorer or Edge it works.